# how do you solve a recurrence $T(n) = T(n/2) + T(3n/4) + (n)^d$

Tags: functions, summation, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computer-science

Here is what I have tried, but I am having trouble completing the last step, i.e.

How do I find the $$\sum_{i=0}^{log_\frac{4}{3}(n-1)}{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{2id}}$$

[image]

If I treat it as constant, the solution does not generalize, I guess. Your help is appreciated.

edit_1: couple of mistakes in the image

1. there should be $T(1).(4/3)^{log_{4/3}n} $ at the work at the last layer=leaves layer
2. there should be $ + O(n)$ after each of the step at the bottom left corner

edit_2: possible answer

If you look through CLRS, there is an exercise just after the proof of the master theorem 4.6.2

And if we apply the answer of 4.6.2 here, then answer to this problem would be $n^d*log_{4/3}n$. It makes sense to argue on these lines. The work done at each level times the number of levels.

But still how to prove it, so that it is formal?

Comment: Presumably you mean that the written expression is equal to $T(n)$, but it would be good to be clear about that.

Comment: Can you explain where that sum came from? Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: each layer of the recursion tree has the amount of work ${({{(5/4)}^i*n}})^{d}$. The maximum level of the tree can be $log_{4/3}(n)$, so to find out total amount of work, I am summing them up. $i$ here is the depth of the recursion tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve the recurrence $$T(x)=T\left(\frac{x}2\right)+T\left(\frac{3x}{4}\right)+x^d$$

We use the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) to determine the asymptotic behavior of $T(x)$. We have:

$$g(x)=x^d\\k=2\\a_1=a_2=1\\b_1=\frac12\quad b_2=\frac34\\h_1(x)=h_2(x)=0$$

We find the value $p$ for which $a_1b_1^p+a_2b_2^p=1$. It turns out that $p\approx 1.507$

The Akra-Bazzi method then states that $$T(x)\in \Theta\left(x^p\left(1+\int_1^x\frac{g(u)}{u^{p+1}}\,du\right)\right)$$

Evaluating the integral, we have that $$T(x)\in\Theta\left(x^p\left(1+\int_1^xu^{d-p-1}\,du \right)\right)\\
T(x)\in\Theta\left(x^p\left(1+\left[\frac{u^{d-p}}{d-p}\right]_1^x \right)\right)\\
T(x)\in\Theta\left(x^p+x^d\right)$$

If we assume that $d\ge p$ then $$T(x)\in\Theta\left(x^d\right)$$

---

OLD ANSWER: 
I haven't checked to make sure the sum you provide is actually what you want, but here it goes anyway: You want to evaluate the sum, which I label $f(n)$: $$f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{\log_\frac43 (n-1)}\left(\frac54\right)^{2id}$$

This is a finite geometric sum, so we simplify to get it in the form $\sum r^i$:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_\frac43 (n-1)}\left(\frac{5^{2d}}{4^{2d}}\right)^{i}=
\sum_{i=0}^{\log_\frac43 (n-1)}\left(\frac{25^{d}}{16^{d}}\right)^{i}$$

Using the formula $\sum_{i=0}^nr^i=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ we obtain:

$$\frac{1-\left(\frac{25^d}{16^d}\right)^{\log_{\frac43}(n-1)+1}}{1-\frac{25^d}{16^d}}=
\frac{1-\frac{25^d}{16^d}\left(\frac54\right)^{2d\log_{\frac43}(n-1)}}{\frac{16^d-25^d}{16^d}}=
\frac{16^d-25^d\left(\frac54\right)^{2d\log_{\frac43}(n-1)}}{16^d-25^d}$$

Now this is a very ugly expression, but I'm assuming you want to find a function $g(n)$ such that $f(n)=O(g(n))$, given the Computer Science nature of your problem.

$$f(n)=O\left(\left(\frac54\right)^{\frac{2d\log_\frac54(n-1)}{\log_\frac54{\frac43}}}\right) =
O\left((n-1)^\frac{2d}{\log_\frac54\frac43}\right)=
O\left(n^\frac{2d}{\log_\frac54\frac43}\right)\approx O\left(n^{1.55132\,d}\right)$$

Comment: The summation makes sense. I appreciate it. However, the upper bound does not seem right to me. The purpose of this kind of problem is to have a "formula" in place so that it is generic enough. If I write a problem with $d = 1$, vs $d=2$, the rate of growth seems constant, i.e. by the factor of 1.55132. I am not sure if this could be true. What do you think? Moreover, I do not have a source to make sure the path till the summation is correct. Do you think I should open a different question for that?

Comment: Actually, I think the sum you provided isn't what you want. I think I know how to answer your question directly from the recurrence relation you provide. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: i have not studied the Akra-Bazzi method, but i will accept your answer, it makes sense. thank you so much.